# Ubuntu 12.04 liveusb/cd - Mount in Read Write Mode?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

How do you mount a drive (internal or external) in READ/WRITE mode using the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD / USB?

I can boot the computer with the LiveUSB but Ubuntu is only mounting the drives as read only ...

Answer (score 8):

You can remount in read-write mode by running:

`sudo mount -o remount,rw <filesystem>`

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive is mounted as read/write from the ubuntu live cd/usb. The disk is mounted when you click on the drive icon on the GUI, or issue a `mount` command in the terminal. The only thing is that you have to use `sudo` to issue command to write to the disk.

For an example, the disks are mounted to `/media/ubuntu/disk1` and `/media/ubuntu/disk2`  You want to copy some files from `disk2` to `disk1`, then run following command (with `sudo`)

```
sudo touch /media/ubuntu/disk2/file.txt 
sudo cp /media/ubuntu/disk2/file.txt /media/ubuntu/disk1/file.txt
```

It works as well in ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04